# How to synchronize Flyway migration files after varchar size in the table changed manually?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, flyway

When learning Spring-boot I used a Flyway migration file to create tables in my mysql database. Then after some time I changed some of the varchar sizes in those tables manually. What should I do now to synchronize the information in the Flyway sql file with the actual values in the tables?

Edit: I can not reverse the sizes in the tables because the tables already contain data that would be too long after reversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach would be to edit the sql in the original migration to match what you eventually settled on. Once done run [Flyway repair](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair). This will update the checksum in the schema history to match the checksum of the migration on disk.

Only do this once you are sure that the sql will produce the same result as you configured manually.